# internet explorer - Are you sure you want to leave this page message

Tags: magento-1.7, error

My site on internet explorer throws up the following popup every time you try and click a link to a new page.

Are you sure you want to leave this page?
Message from webpage: 
null

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What version on IE? Have you tried on multiple computers? Is it on a specific page of your site? Can you post a link to your site?

Comment: Check Different version of IE. and let us know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An "do you want to leave" message comes most times from some javascript, which was added afterwards.

Please look at your added javascript libraries, which implements such messages and give them a bug report.

That is in no point of view a magento problem/question.

For the case you are only a user, not a developer: deactivate 3rd party modules module by module and see which one causes this problem.